# Unable to sum the flags set to 1 in PowerBI Matrix visualization

Tags: powerbi, dax, tableau-api, powerbi-desktop

I am facing an issue in PowerBI matrix visualization.I have a school table with column values Student_ID,Location and AttendanceDate.

I need to find the sum of the number of times each student who **attended classes >=1** days per location per month.

I have created a custom measure named Attendance as stated below to calculate students who the **attended classes >=1**

```
Attendance = IF(DISTINCTCOUNT(school[Attendance_Date])>=1,1,0)
```

In my visualization, I am able to get all the flags which is set to '1' for all the students who meet the condition of attending classes>=1.But as per my requirement  I want to get the sum of these 1 flags to get the number of times all students attended classes >=1 per location per month.My final visualization should not contain the student ID, it should only have the location and months and the sum of the flags set to 1 indicating the number of times students attended the classes >=1 .

**Expected Output:-**

```
Location    January        February     March 
Chennai       1              1             1
Delhi         2              2             2
Goa           0              2             0
```

I tried to implement the fixed LOD concept as we do in tableau to handle this scenario in PowerBI but no luck.

I created a  calculated measure 'CalculateAttendance as below but it is not working :-

```
CalculateAttendance = CALCULATE((school[Attendance]),ALLEXCEPT(school[Student_ID],school[Location],school[Attendance]))
```

Could you please provide any changes to my above calculations to resolve this issue.Please suggest how can I handle it or modify my calculations.

Regards
Sameer

[My current matrix visualization in PowerBI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykmTc.jpg)

**Input data source [text/excel[any]] for powerBi**

```
Attendance  Student_ID location
01.01.2017  100 Delhi
02.01.2017  100 Delhi
03.01.2017  100 Delhi
04.01.2017  100 Delhi
05.01.2017  100 Delhi
06.01.2017  100 Delhi
01.01.2017  101 Delhi
02.01.2017  101 Delhi
03.01.2017  101 Delhi
04.01.2017  101 Delhi
05.01.2017  101 Delhi
06.01.2017  101 Delhi
08.01.2017  101 Delhi
09.01.2017  102 Chennai
01.01.2017  102 Chennai
02.01.2017  102 Chennai
03.01.2017  102 Chennai
04.01.2017  102 Chennai
05.01.2017  102 Chennai
06.01.2017  102 Chennai
08.01.2017  102 Chennai
11.01.2017  102 Chennai
01.02.2017  101 Delhi
02.02.2017  101 Delhi
03.02.2017  101 Delhi
04.02.2017  101 Delhi
05.02.2017  101 Delhi
06.02.2017  101 Delhi
01.02.2017  100 Delhi
02.02.2017  100 Delhi
03.02.2017  100 Delhi
04.02.2017  100 Delhi
05.02.2017  100 Delhi
06.02.2017  100 Delhi
01.02.2017  102 Chennai
02.02.2017  102 Chennai
03.02.2017  102 Chennai
04.02.2017  102 Chennai
05.02.2017  102 Chennai
06.02.2017  102 Chennai
01.02.2017  103 Goa
02.02.2017  103 Goa
03.02.2017  103 Goa
04.02.2017  103 Goa
05.02.2017  103 Goa
06.02.2017  103 Goa
01.02.2017  104 Goa
02.02.2017  104 Goa
03.02.2017  104 Goa
04.02.2017  104 Goa
01.03.2017  100 Delhi
02.03.2017  100 Delhi
03.03.2017  100 Delhi
04.03.2017  100 Delhi
05.03.2017  100 Delhi
06.03.2017  100 Delhi
01.03.2017  101 Delhi
02.03.2017  101 Delhi
03.03.2017  101 Delhi
04.03.2017  101 Delhi
05.03.2017  101 Delhi
06.03.2017  101 Delhi
08.03.2017  101 Delhi
09.03.2017  102 Chennai
01.03.2017  102 Chennai
02.03.2017  102 Chennai
03.03.2017  102 Chennai
04.03.2017  102 Chennai
05.03.2017  102 Chennai
```

Comment: Actually, with your sample data in Goa you have 2 students in january: 103 and 104, why in your expected data you have 0 instead?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need the number of distinct students per month/location

This measure produces this matrix

```
# Students = DISTINCTCOUNT( School[Student_ID] )
```

[image: location matrix]

To verify it at the students level, here it is the same matrix with students detail

[image: location matrix with students]

Comment: I put the sample pbix on my github, this is the direct link for the download https://github.com/SergioMurru/shared/raw/main/sameer%20Unable%20to%20sum%20the%20flags%20set%20to%201%20in%20PowerBI%20Matrix%20visualization/sameer%20Unable%20to%20sum%20the%20flags%20set%20to%201%20in%20PowerBI%20Matrix%20visualization.pbix

Comment: Actually i need to evaluate the flag value as 1 for all the students with >=1 attendance days and then add these flags .Here flags denote number of times the student swiped in in a month .so if i add all the flags ,i can get the number of times students swiped in a month per location with swipe days >=1...The above one you sent is distinct count of the number of students ,its little different.

Comment: Attendance = IF(DISTINCTCOUNT(school[Attendance_Date])>=1,1,0)  this condition is for the flag to be set to 1 for each student id per month per location.I need to find sum of all 1 to get the number of times the condition occured.Student who atleast attended >=1 days in a month.In actual scenario it is 12 days ,i wanted to understand how to add this logic so i gave less data in sample input in my query..Hope the scenario is clear

Comment: So if a student attends 12 days in a month, Attendance value is 1. I really cannot see the difference. Can you please expand your sample data, enough to show the difference in one of the two matrix I posted in my answer?